# SAS Log File Parse w/ RegEx + NXLog

Tags: regex, parsing, logging, sas

We have a SAS application that I need to gather logging data for. I'm seeing some rough structure, but having some issues reliable capturing the data.

Here's a sample of the log output:

```
NOTE: There were 5 observations read from the data set APP.NEW_FEATURE.
      WHERE feature_status_id=0;
NOTE: The data set WORK._NULL has 5 observations and 9 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
TRACE : RM_FORECAST_JOB "Entering Macro"
TRACE : RM_FORECAST_JOB "Entering Macro"
NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set IN_XML.requestHeader.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

And here is the RegEx that should work, but I fear might be overcomplicated:

```
((^\S+\s*:\s*.+)\R(^\s+.+\R)*)
```

When I test in [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) (w/ global + multiline options) - the fields I need are highlighted but I get no results when I test in [NXLog](http://nxlog.org/).

I suspect the verbosity of the expression is partly to blame, but I'm new to RegEx and have been learning as I go.

**EDIT**: I'm hoping to create a regex match against each event i.e. a match for each of the following using a singular expression.

```
NOTE: There were 5 observations read from the data set APP.NEW_FEATURE.
      WHERE feature_status_id=0;
```

AND

```
NOTE: The data set WORK._NULL has 5 observations and 9 variables.
```

Comment: What part of the log are you trying to match?

Comment: I'm trying to capture all of the above. I need a singular expression that solves for both log entry variants; messages containing a severity and message - and ones that _also_ have message data indented below them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your new expression, I didn't get any results ... until I changed the first `\r` to `\R` (`\r` doesn't mean anything in Regex, but `\R` means capture newlines (`LF` or `CRLF`), is this what you wanted?).

Here are the results: http://www.rexfiddle.net/tsVjnVe

Is this what you were after? It would be more helpful if you explained what exactly you did or did not want to capture with your expression.

**Edit:** Setting the Ignore Case flag captured more: http://www.rexfiddle.net/8Sf8NLd

---

**Edit 2:** Try this expression:

```
(.+?): (.+?)\r?\n((?:\s+.+(?:\r?\n|$))*)
```

Here's a sample of what it does:

http://www.rexfiddle.net/GyeJslR

A basic explanation of the expression: It will capture anything before a `:`, then anything after the `:` through to the end of the line, then it will look for subsequent lines that are indented (with spaces or tabs), and capture each of those until it finds either a line that is no longer indented, or the end of the file/string.

Capture group 1 is the log category (NOTE, TRACE in your example).
Capture group 2 is the log message (everything after NOTE:, for example).
Capture group 3 is the indented messages underneath the main log message.

**NOTE:** Depending on how SAS interperets and runs Regex, you might have to change this expression a little - line breaks are handled a little differently depending on what flavor of Regex you're using. If it doesn't work, try substituting both of the `\r?\n` for `\R` or an actual string linebreak (however you do that with SAS).

Comment: I think the difference between \r and \R may depend on the implementation/language where it's in use. I gave it a try anyway - and didn't receive the desired results.

Comment: @weird.turned.pro Again, please update your question to indicate what you're trying to capture or not capture as part of your expression. You gave sample data and your regular expression, which is good, but we don't know what you want the outcome to be, so we can't help you any further.

Comment: Added some detail that hopefully clarifies what I'm aiming for a bit. Each log event begins with the '{SEVERITY} : {MESSAGE}' construct - and the indented information may or may not be there.

Comment: That was more helpful, I've written an expression that might be more what you're looking for, give it a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: I reduced the expression a bit, but your answer ultimately led me to it. You wouldn't have seen it from the example log snippet, but there are some log events that don't have a uniform spaces between the severity and message around the colon. Here's what I ultimately used if you'd like to edit your answer `(^\S+?\s*:\s*.+(\r?\n\s+.+)*)`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are collecting from a text file. **The im_file module treats every line as a separate event by default** (InputType LineBased). As such, **trying to use multi-line regexp will not work in this case** since it is only one line what you are trying to match against.

You need to make sure that the whole event (not just a single line of it) is available in the context.
See the [xm_multiline](http://nxlog.org/nxlog-docs/en/nxlog-reference-manual.html#xm_multiline) module and the examples. Your regexp should work from there on.

Comment: I actually am using the xm_multiline extension - which needs a HeaderLine definition - hence the need for the RegEx pattern. I've also captured multiline messages directly from im_file (no InputType defined).